# Empty rows when retrieving data from database to dataGridView in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, row, data-retrieval

Why do I get blank rows when I retrieve rows from MySQL database to dataGridView? I end up getting the amount of rows but its empty (it has no text).

this is my code so far:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Data Source = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 0159";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM TopShineDB.Table1 ;", conDataBase);
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
                sda.Update(dt);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check If your query return data or not from database,
After `sda.Fill(dt)` why you used `BindingSource bs` ? Try with commenting this lines and add `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` rathat than bs.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it showed the exact same thing

Comment: check my answer.. let me know if its solution to your prob.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried below code sample to get data from database and bind to datagridview.

```
var ConnectionString = "your ConnectionString";
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("your query");
connect.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
adp.Fill(ds); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = DtSet.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
connect.Close();
```

Comment: I got the exact same result.

Comment: Have you debugged that datatable contains data?

Comment: at the start of the application it has no data. the user later fills it up and then store the data into the database. now I am doing this so at start up the user would be able to load the data from the database.

Comment: Can you please check once datagridview properties whether you changed any default properties ?

Comment: I changed the properties but which one is responsible for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    string conString = @"Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=TopShineDB;User Id=root;password=0159";
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Just Clear your Columns you define in DataGridView *

```
      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = "Data Source = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 0159";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM TopShineDB.Table1 ;", conDataBase);
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

       
                 dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

c#